# TcmSearchHost.exe process memory consumption

Tags: 2011, search, search-engine

We have the following situation: client upgraded from Tridion 5.3 SP1 to 2011 SP1, but is asking questions about the (high) memory consumption of the TcmSearchHost.exe process. It uses up to 900 MB of memory. The search config is default, no tweaking has been done to the SOLR config so far.

I've compared this with amount of RAM used to our other Tridion 2011  projects, and it's indeed higher while the size of the lucene indexes is more or less the same.

Is this still an acceptable memory usage, or could one of you think of ways to optimize/reasons for the 'high' RAM consumption?

Comment: Could you clarify whether this high memory usage is seen after just upgrading and rebuilding the index, or whether this is consistently high after all rebuilds have been performed and after a reboot?

Comment: Solr is java based, JVM could be culprit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks Chris for the info about the restart; the re-indexing was done, but IT confirmed server was not restarted afterwards. A simple restart solved the issue, average RAM usage is now about 300MB (which seems reasonably for the TcmSearchHost.exe process compared with other T2011 projects).